# Problems in creating a sidebar through toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

well i was trying to create a sidebar through toggle and it is not opening the sidebar. Is it possible to create the sidebar with simple javascript that i applied. Please check the javascript and let me know if this is possible in this way. Link of the work is https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/WNJQEmW. Kindly see the work and rectify it.

**CODE**:

```js
function toggleSidebar(menu) {
  menu.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
header {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: coral;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1001;
}

#sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle {
  margin: 0;
  cursor: grab;
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle div {
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.open .bar4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.5px, 5.5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.5px, 5.5px);
}

.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .bar6 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
}

.open .sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 58px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.sidebar-header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar-header img {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-header h6 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


/*--Media-queries--*/

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  #sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle div {
    height: 2px;
  }
  #sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle .bar4 {
    height: 2.5px;
  }
  .sidebar {
    top: 41px;
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="sidebar-toggle" onclick="toggleSidebar(this)">
    <div class="toggle-circle">
      <div class="bar4"></div>
      <div class="bar5"></div>
      <div class="bar6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="sidebar" id='mySidebar' onclick="toggleSidebar(this)">
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <img src="images/4.jpeg">
      <h6>Umann goswami</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  hello world
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I updated your question. Codepens tend to get deleted eventually. It's best to create a snippet within your question for us to work with. I've also included snippets to better organize what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

1. Your toggle was getting the `open` class, but your sidebar didn't
2. If you want to select an element with both classes it has to be `.open.sidebar` and not `.open .sidebar`. `.open .sidebar` will search for an element that has a parent with class `.open`.

I changed your js to this:

```
// grab elements
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')
const toggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle')

// listen for click on the toggle
toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)

function toggleSidebar(e) {
  // toggle classes in both sidebar and toggle
  toggle.classList.toggle('open')
  sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

And your css to this:

```
.open.sidebar {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')
const toggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle')

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)

function toggleSidebar(e) {
  toggle.classList.toggle('open')
  sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
header {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: coral;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1001;
}

#sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle {
  margin: 0;
  cursor: grab;
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle div {
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.open .bar4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.5px, 5.5px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.5px, 5.5px);
}

.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .bar6 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
}

.open.sidebar {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 58px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.sidebar-header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar-header img {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-header h6 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


/*--Media-queries--*/

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: -15px;
  }
  #sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle div {
    height: 2px;
  }
  #sidebar-toggle .toggle-circle .bar4 {
    height: 2.5px;
  }
  .sidebar {
    top: 41px;
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="sidebar-toggle">
    <div class="toggle-circle">
      <div class="bar4"></div>
      <div class="bar5"></div>
      <div class="bar6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="sidebar" id='mySidebar'>
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <img src="images/4.jpeg">
      <h6>Umann goswami</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  hello world
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: it is not working , try running the code snippet, it will move user image to different position.

Comment: That's what your styles do. I can't know how it should look ike.

Comment: simple onclick dissapear and appear on toggle.